# Laravel Packages Testing (PHPUnit)

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, package

I'm confused about Laravel 5 Package and UnitTest

I created a package with following structure

```
Laravel/packages/Abc/Zzz/src/Manual.php
Laravel/packages/Abc/Zzz/tests/testManual.php
Laravel/packages/Abc/Zzz/composer.json
```

inside the manual.php, I used laravel function "File" to open a file, but when I run PHPUnit to test my class, it shows

```
1) Abc\Zzz\tests\testManual::testManual
Error: Class 'File' not found
```

what do I need to "use" the library for my class.

Thanks in advance :)

More Information
Laravel/packages/Abc/Zzz/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "Abc/Zzz",
    "description": "This is a private pakcage for Abc Zzz Project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "email": ""
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Abc\\Zzz\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Abc\\Zzz\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE
I put the following to package composer.json

```
"illuminate/filesystem": "5.4.*"
```

and ran composer install
but I still can't use File Facades.
it shows

```
RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the default laravel Filesystem, it also seems, that you should import File so try

`use File;` or `\File`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I already added use File in Manual.php, but showing the same error, I edited the post (composer.json), it don't have any laravel Filesystem inside the packages folder.

Comment: I want to save the package to Github Individually, and use Jenkins to test this package with Unit Test, then, create a blank new laravel project, composer require this package, and do the Integration Test.